# cant create azure function new function buttons remain disabled

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have existing Azure function app. I want to create a new function in it but "New function" button remain disabled.

I m account owner so should no be issue of previliges

[image: Function App Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your **Function app edit mode** has been set to **Read Only**. You could go to **Function app settings**, set it **Read/Write** like the screenshot, then it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: You first need to understand why it became read-only in the first place. If you deployed from git, VS or VSTS, you should never make changes from the Portal, as you will lose them on the next deployment. There is a valid valid reason for it to be read-only.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thank you David，I agree with you.